# i2d_X509_REQ_INFO doesn't convert req_info structure properly

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, openssl, pkcs#11

We are working on tokens to generate CSR (certificate signing requests). Keypair is generating perfectly in token but we are unable to get proper csr.
I'm trying to create X509 certificate request signed inside smart card using PKCS11 interface. I’m using openssl-1.0.2.

To perform this task I have to perform following steps:
1, create certificate request (X509_new)
2, load public key (X509_REQ_set_pubkey)
3, set up subject name and extensions as required
4, export req_info structure (i2d_X509_REQ_INFO)
5, sign this structure using PKCS11

Unfortunately created request doesn't contain valid signature. After closer look at the openssl calls I've noticed, that the buffer exported using i2d_X509_REQ_INFO function doesn't contain properly encoded structure. 
Can somebody help me, what I'm doing wrong, or which parameter of the structure I forgot to initialize?

```
Relevant part of the code:

...
  X509_REQ *req;
  X509_NAME *subj;

  if (!(req = X509_REQ_new())) {
    printf("Unable to initialize X509_REQ structure\n");
    return -1;
  }

  RSA *rsa;
  rsa = RSA_new();
  rsa->e = BN_bin2bn( (unsigned char *) pub_publicExponent, (int) 3, NULL );
  rsa->n = BN_bin2bn( (unsigned char *) modulus, (int) (pub_modulusbits/8), NULL );

  if( (pkey = EVP_PKEY_new()) == NULL ) {
    printf("Unable to initialize PKEY structure\n");
    return -1;
  }

  EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA( pkey , rsa );
  X509_REQ_set_pubkey(req, pkey);

  subj=X509_REQ_get_subject_name(req);
  X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(subj,"C",
                          MBSTRING_ASC, (unsigned char *)"SK", -1, -1, 0);
  X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(subj,"CN",
                          MBSTRING_ASC, (unsigned char *)"Test", -1, -1, 0);

  int datasig_len;
  unsigned char *tobesigned;
  datasig_len = i2d_X509_REQ_INFO( req->req_info, NULL );
  tobesigned = (unsigned char *) malloc( datasig_len );
  if( !tobesigned ) {
    printf("Unable to alloc mem buffer\n");
    return -1;
  }
  int zzz = i2d_X509_REQ_INFO( req->req_info, &tobesigned );
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have overlooked a part of the [relevant documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/d2i_X509_fp.html) (which, admittedly, happens very easily):

> i2d_X509() encodes the structure pointed to by x into DER format. If
>   out is not NULL is writes the DER encoded data to the buffer at *out,
>   **and increments it to point after the data just written**. If the return
>   value is negative an error occurred, otherwise it returns the length
>   of the encoded data.

(Note that this snippet takes `i2d_X509()` as the example, but it works the same for `i2d_X509_REQ_INFO()`)

Before invoking the `i2d` function, you have to store the value of `tobesigned` so you can refer to it afterwards.

Recreating your example, it does seem to contain a valid DER-formatted representation of your structure, since it seems to go in the reverse direction without problems. This is illustrated by the following snippet:

```
  unsigned char *ptr = tobesigned;
  int zzz = i2d_X509_REQ_INFO( req->req_info, &ptr );
  const unsigned char *ptr2 = tobesigned;
  X509_REQ_INFO *deser = d2i_X509_REQ_INFO(NULL, &ptr2, zzz);
  printf("Result of i2d|d2i_X509_REQ_INFO: \n"
         "  zzz        = %d\n"
         "  tobesigned = 0x%p\n"
         "  ptr        = 0x%p\n"
         "  ptr2       = 0x%p\n"
         "  deser      = 0x%p\n",
         zzz, tobesigned, ptr, ptr2, deser);
```

It yields:

```
Result of i2d|d2i_X509_REQ_INFO: 
  zzz        = 198
  tobesigned = 0x0x7fd09c403010
  ptr        = 0x0x7fd09c4030d6
  ptr2       = 0x0x7fd09c4030d6
  deser      = 0x0x7fd09c402f60
```